# Custom TextView in RecyclerView items stopped ItemClickListener to call (Existing solutions are not working)

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview, android-custom-view

I have many child in item of my Recyclerview.When i tapped on a textview which is a cutsom textview Recyclerview item click stopped working while clicking on rest child items didn't create this issue. I tried all the available solutions like by  doing

- focusable="false"
- focusableinTouchmode="false"
- descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants" etc

that are available already on stackoverflow. But custom textview didn't allow working of ItemClickListener.

Any idea regarding this issue?

Comment: What is custom textview & how did you attach ItemClickListener to recycler view? It will be helpful if you post some code.

Comment: Custom textview is programatically created and then used in xml.
Yeah i attached item click listener and it is working but not working when we touch on textview

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved this issue, a field i found in my textview xml android:inputType="textNoSuggestions" which is creating problem. I removed that field and problem get resolved.

Answer (score 1):

```
    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
     private View view;

    public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        view=itemView;
    }
}
```

then in your `onBindViewHolder`

```
 holder.view.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {

                   // your logic
                }
            });
```

this will make your entire row clickable

hope this can help you !

Comment: @MuhammadZahabAhmedKhan  post some code so that we can understand  what's the problem